# How do I know which application is streaming to my TV

Tags: windows, windows-10, video-streaming

From the TV, in the sources list, there is "Network - DESKTOP-TXXXXXXX", which is my PC's name. From there, I can access 3 specific directories (clearly hand-picked) and play videos directly from there. I would like to change these directories, but I don't know which PC application is making these video files available for streaming. It is probably something I, or someone else in the family, installed years ago, and that was unused since then. I have looked at the list of installed application (from control panel/uninstall) and nothing rings a bell.

Can someone please guess which application is allowing my PC to stream to TV?

[image: u1]

[image: u2]

[image: u3]

[image: u4]

[image: u5]

[image: taskman]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have probably at some time in the past turned on [Media Streaming](https://www.howtogeek.com/215400/how-to-turn-your-computer-into-a-dlna-media-server/), which is a built-in Windows 10 feature and not a separate application. Search for "options for media streaming" from the search bar to turn it on or off or change basic settings.

Enabling Media Streaming turns your Windows 10 PC into a ["DLNA"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_Living_Network_Alliance) server. Most media streaming devices and (Smart) TVs support streaming through a DLNA Server and can automatically find them in your network.

Windows 10 Media Streaming uses the "Music", "Pictures" and "Videos" libraries for streaming content. you can add folders to those libraries or change their location from the File Explorer under "This PC".

Comment: This seems interesting, but when I check "Media streaming options", it says that "Media streaming is not turned on". I think this means that it is something else sharing my 3 directories, right?

Please note that the directories from which I can stream are very specific folders I created, like E:\video\HorrorFilm

Comment: You might be able to find out the name of the application by starting a command prompt with administrator rights (right click `cmd.exe` and choose `run as administrator`), and looking at the output of the command `netstat -a -b -n`. Look for the application(s) listening on UDP port 1900 or TCP port 2869.

Comment: I don't see anything special here, this is the output of the command:  https://shrib.com/#netstatcarlo

Comment: I'm seeing  [wmpnetwk.exe] TCP 0.0.0.0:2869 LISTENING in your output. *wmpnetwk*.exe is the Windows Media Streaming component. AFAIK this should not be running if you're not sharing media with Windows Media Streaming, which is strange because Media Streaming is not turned on on your PC.

Comment: It seems you are right: the streaming comes from Windows Media Streaming, even if in theory it should be disabled. I enabled the media streaming (from "Network and Sharing Center"), changed the name of the media library (which was originally "user") and the new name appeared on my TV screen. I will see how to configure or disable it, but you definitely answered my question.